# Верстка блок новостей

Tags: css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть небольшой блок, который я хотел, но не смог сверстать.
Проблема заключается в том что я просто не понимаю как все выровнять и чтобы все было адекватно и сохранялась адаптивность.
Помогите сверстать этот блок пожалуйста или подскажите что да как сделать.
Важно чтобы сохранялась адаптивность. Ну например чтобы при маленьком экране содержание было под фоткой.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ: на чистом css)

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте ваш код.

Comment: Кода нет тк я даже не знаю счего начать. Ну хорошо <div id="news"><div/> а дальше что как лучше сделать я не понимаю. Да я даже не прошу код скидывать если кому сложно помочь, то просто объяснить хотябы на понятном языке с чего начать

Comment: Для начала сделайте `html` разметку.  А потом уже будет стилизация.  Для данного случая подходит `float`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую прочитать про flexbox, очень элегантный  способ для построения layout

```css
body
{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.news-cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.news-cont .content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.news-cont .content img {
  float: right;
}

.news-cont .hud
{
  display: flex;
  
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.news-cont .hud .links a
{
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.publish-date
{
  color: #777;
}
.news-cont .content .title
{
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<section class="news-cont">
  <div class="hud">
    <h1 class="title">Breaking News</h1>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="/">Reddit</a>
      <a href="/">facebook</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <article class="content">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" alt="img" width="200">
    <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
    <p class="publish-date">Publish date</p>
    
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime tempora ab ullam id ratione odio recusandae vel tenetur, nemo, eligendi mollitia vero placeat, officiis non! Error vel officiis omnis aut? ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, amet maiores, inventore optio quae sequi mollitia laudantium illum, dolore distinctio quo architecto earum impedit laborum, sit animi nisi quibusdam hic. ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, a eveniet, sint ipsam tempora at voluptates eaque velit! Distinctio velit maxime nostrum corporis aspernatur, voluptatem. Pariatur soluta ipsum, cum eius.</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Конечно даже не близко как на картинке) но спасибо за совет про flexbox и за пример.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков поменял картинку местами в DOM, сейчас почти идентично

Comment: А да вот увидел, все теперь полное спасибо)

Comment: А вот последний маленький вопрос возник. Я добавил ваш код и у меня этот блок новостей выходит за свои пределы при экране 600px. Как это исправить не подскажите?

Comment: Почитайте про media запросы

Comment: Да я знаю что это. Просто как убрать эти выходы за пределы?

Comment: Покажите картинку

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: @ПавелЕриков вероятно вы переопределяете мои стили своими

Comment: А да извиняюсь не заметил что у section высота стоит 250px вот все и выходит. Еще раз спасибо за помощь

Comment: @ПавелЕриков https://imgur.com/8uKqwQx

Answer (score 3):

Цвета шрифты ну и некоторые моменты с `margin` оставлю Вам

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-left h2">Новость</div>
            <div class="col text-right">fds</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
            <p class="text-justify"> 
                <img class="float-right ml-4 mb-4" src="https://bugaga.ru/uploads/posts/2014-06/1402471536_prikoly-6.jpg" width="30%" height="auto">
                01.01.2019<br>Заголовок<br>
                <br>
                <br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, corporis. Dolore quo cumque excepturi numquam impedit voluptates pariatur repellendus quibusdam sapiente autem ullam illo quasi eos reiciendis, provident tempore nulla.
                Ad quod explicabo alias illum culpa. Itaque officiis rem quia eius? Ipsa aperiam architecto laboriosam quis veniam, fuga accusamus ex, dignissimos ut nam quasi eos velit molestiae deserunt iure perferendis?
                Quo laboriosam odit voluptates fugit tempore ducimus voluptas corporis laborum tenetur officiis, saepe id necessitatibus similique quidem! Provident architecto necessitatibus voluptate earum corporis quas omnis, hic suscipit impedit? Earum, reiciendis?
                Consequatur inventore maxime perspiciatis quaerat ullam deleniti cumque consequuntur laudantium nisi tempore ipsa sapiente, ex dolor reiciendis odit temporibus, voluptates dicta soluta numquam officia, quae dolorum itaque eveniet. Cupiditate, laboriosam.
                Quae alias optio neque nisi ipsam amet commodi laboriosam hic tenetur incidunt veritatis reprehenderit expedita impedit officiis maiores, odio ipsum quis quaerat voluptatem. Corporis a animi molestias aliquam dignissimos eveniet?
                Provident nesciunt adipisci nemo a officiis, consequatur nisi, consequuntur possimus laboriosam quibusdam placeat non blanditiis? Reiciendis saepe repellat, iusto placeat cupiditate, at, explicabo animi vero iure maxime doloremque numquam fugit?
                Aliquam quasi quibusdam in sit. Officia soluta maiores voluptate mollitia consequatur voluptatibus a, animi rem? Enim suscipit deleniti similique, beatae, veniam, possimus ipsum ut hic velit harum tempore ex quia!
                Rem fugiat ex impedit eum eaque facere, nobis amet deleniti tempore recusandae similique voluptates enim id, qui quasi quidem quia sed commodi maiores. Numquam, soluta praesentium beatae assumenda dicta possimus?
                Est atque, officiis dolorem ratione magni consequatur explicabo voluptatem incidunt modi temporibus facilis ad necessitatibus laborum labore quos asperiores ipsam repellat tempora nihil sunt dicta ea facere qui minima. Quam.
                Aspernatur quas unde voluptatibus obcaecati impedit harum officia dolore similique ratione dolores, blanditiis sit aut itaque debitis in et nobis nesciunt neque eaque quia quis necessitatibus? Tenetur inventore adipisci ullam?
                Natus corporis animi ipsam, provident ex delectus, minus dolor quis veritatis voluptatem vitae id quidem eum voluptate fugiat quo nobis possimus ea consectetur. Atque nulla deleniti itaque sint, perferendis veniam.
                Ad harum quasi excepturi, illo aliquid vel eaque obcaecati est! Ipsum, accusantium sint porro dolorem dignissimos tenetur maiores nisi voluptatum illum temporibus. Minima, saepe minus molestiae atque nemo corporis deleniti?
                Possimus quod quibusdam, nesciunt consequuntur minus dolor sed. Repellat impedit molestias amet architecto quas dolores iusto a commodi dolor vitae delectus reiciendis omnis obcaecati voluptas fugit quis saepe, repudiandae accusamus.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот и создаете в своем css класс `container`  и пишите туда стили, которые увидили

Comment: Ббаааллинн, извиняюсь вы дали очень хороший ответ и спасибо вам за него, но я забыл уточнить что без bootstrap и тд. На чистом css. Еще раз извиняюсь.

Comment: ну скопипастите нужные классы css, и будет вам тоже самое без бутстрапа...

Comment: Не подскажите как это сделать? Просто я что то ничего не нашел в интернете.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков дополнил ответ